Faceted Boxplot - values/data structure
I'm having difficulty making the data for the boxplot fit what I'm trying to show.
Basically, I want the first fasceted boxplot for "tumor" to have the values 2.97 and 2.97 for the first boxplot, 2.9 and 2.97 for the second boxplot, and just 2.6 for the third boxplot (just a line).
And for "adjacent lung", 1.5 and 2.25; 2.97 and 2.5; and 2.37.
And for "tissue far from tumor", 2.5 and 2.8; 2.5 and 2.1; and 3.
I don't know why it's coming out strangely in the graph (see image).
I jittered it so that I could see the points clearly.
Not sure what data structure to use here. Please help.
See code below:
x <- c(2.97, 2.97, 1.5, 2.25, 2.5, 2.8)
y <- c(2.9, 2.97, 2.97, 2.5, 2.5, 2.1)
z <- c(2.6, 2.97, 3)

data <- data.frame(
  values = c(x, y, z),
  group = factor(
    c(rep("y", length(y)), rep("x", length(x)), rep("z", length(z))),
    levels = c("x", "y", "z")
  ),
  position = factor(
    rep(c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor"), length(x) + length(y) + length(z)),
    levels = c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor")
  )
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = values, fill = position)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(fill=group), size=5, shape=21, colour="grey20",
             position=position_jitter(width=0.2, height=0.1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("x" = "Case 1, 4", "y" = "Case 2, 3", "z" = "Case 5")) +
  labs(title = "IL-13 Receptor alpha 1 positivity scores",
       x = "Patient Cases", y = "Positivity scores") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12, angle = 45),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12, angle = 45)) +
  facet_wrap(~ position)

I tried putting in 10 as a value just to see what would happen, but I'm still not sure what the problem is.


welcome to SO. Could you explain better what is strange?

Basically I don't understand why there are three dots for the last value, when it depends on a single number. Is my data structure correct? And, the first boxplot in the graph (leftmost) should be a single value (2.97, 2.97), so why is it giving me a full boxplot?

You have 15 data points (12 x, 12 y and 3z), but they are triplicate in data, and it appears x and yvalues are swapped.
Look:
> distinct(data) %>% arrange(group)
   values group              position
1    2.90     x                 tumor
2    2.97     x         adjacent lung
3    2.97     x tissue far from tumor
4    2.50     x                 tumor
5    2.50     x         adjacent lung
6    2.10     x tissue far from tumor
7    2.97     y                 tumor
8    2.97     y         adjacent lung
9    1.50     y tissue far from tumor
10   2.25     y                 tumor
11   2.50     y         adjacent lung
12   2.80     y tissue far from tumor
13   2.60     z                 tumor
14   2.97     z         adjacent lung
15   3.00     z tissue far from tumor

Plot with dplyr::distinct(data) will give you the graphic below: does it makes more sense?


Yes. That's closer to what I want... why were the values appearing in triplicate, may I ask?

@kakashi1992 Because the way you build your data data frame. values = c(x, y, z) and group = factor(rep(c(... are size "15", but position = factor(rep(c... is 45. This way, values and group are recycled two times.

Is there any way to alter the data frame itself it make it so the values aren't repeated twice like that?

Also, can you by any chance share your code?

@kakashi1992 the code is exactly  the same, just replacing data with distinct(data)!

“Is there any way to alter..”: yes, I’ll help you when I’m on my pc!

I was able to make the thing I wanted.

# Define the data vectors
x <- c(2.97, 1.5,2.5, 2.97, 2.25, 2.8)
y <- c(2.9, 2, 2.5, 2.97, 2.5, 2.1)
z <- c(2.6, 2.97, 3)

#for "adjacent lung", 1.5 and 2.25; 2.97 and 2.5; and 2.37. And for "tissue far from tumor", 2.5 and 2.8; 2.5 and 2.1; and 3.
#l  And for "adjacent lung", 1.5 and 2.25; 2.97 and 2.5; and 2.37. And for "tissue far from tumor", 2.5 and 2.8; 2.5 and 2.1; and 3.

# Create separate data frames for each group
data_x <- data.frame(values = x, group = factor(rep("x", length(x))), 
                     position = factor(rep(c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor"), length.out = length(x)), 
                                       levels = c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor")))
data_y <- data.frame(values = y, group = factor(rep("y", length(y))), 
                     position = factor(rep(c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor"), length.out = length(y)), 
                                       levels = c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor")))
data_z <- data.frame(values = z, group = factor(rep("z", length(z))), 
                     position = factor(rep(c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor"), length.out = length(z)), 
                                       levels = c("tumor", "adjacent lung", "tissue far from tumor")))

# Combine the data frames into a single data frame
data <- rbind(data_x, data_y, data_z)

# Load ggplot2 library
library(ggplot2)

# Plot the data
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = values, fill = position)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(fill=group), size=5, shape=21, colour="grey20",
             position=position_jitter(width=0.2, height=0.1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("x" = "Case 1, 4", "y" = "Case 2, 3", "z" = "Case 5")) +
  labs(title = "IL-13 Receptor alpha 1 positivity scores",
       x = "Patient Cases", y = "Positivity scores") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12, angle = 45),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 12)) +
  facet_wrap(~ position)

